# How to check if user select text?

Tags: monaco-editor

I want to implement this work:

1.When user select SQL text in Monaco,we execute selected SQL.

2.When user not select any SQL text,we execute all SQL in editor.

Can you tell me how to check if user select text?

Answer (score 0):

The API is `Monaco.getSelection()` which returns `null` if no text is selected.